# How many XML sitemap can generate for one site and is it hammer to SEO ranking?

Tags: seo, xml-sitemap

How many XML sitemap can generate for one site and is it hammer to SEO ranking?

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index):

> You can provide multiple Sitemap files, but each Sitemap file that you
>   provide must have no more than 50,000 URLs and must be no larger than
>   10MB (10,485,760 bytes). If you would like, you may compress your
>   Sitemap files using gzip to reduce your bandwidth requirement; however
>   the sitemap file once uncompressed must be no larger than 10MB. If you
>   want to list more than 50,000 URLs, you must create multiple Sitemap
>   files.
>
> If you do provide multiple Sitemaps, you should then list each Sitemap
>   file in a Sitemap index file. Sitemap index files may not list more
>   than 50,000 Sitemaps and must be no larger than 10MB (10,485,760
>   bytes) and can be compressed. You can have more than one Sitemap index
>   file. The XML format of a Sitemap index file is very similar to the
>   XML format of a Sitemap file.

Naturally, if you are allowed to have multiple sitemaps it is not harmful to your SEO efforts.